# Slideshow Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a slideshow javascript running on my website but it doesn't seem to be working properly when I change the images back and forth and the automaticity doesn't show image 6. Could someone please help me write it up because I have been trying over a month and reached nowhere.
https://wbd-ownwork-13--15nalaas.repl.co/

```
    <script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
 showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
 showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
 var i;
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
 var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
 if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
 for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
 }
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
 captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
   var i;
   var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
   }
   slideIndex++;
   if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 2} 
   slides[slideIndex-2].style.display = "block";
   setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: change through the images using the gallery on the homepage and see how the whole thong screws up as well.

Comment: You need to add the relevant code to your question. Links to your website are not suitable for Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: You never `clearTimeout`, so with every click, you create a new timeout that advances the slideshow independently. `slideIndex` is declared twice and used inconsistently. Why not 0-base it throughout the entire code?

Comment: @Xufox how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need not to add the custom controls for changing the slides because the slide show is more than enough.
And secondly you need to change the entire script to the given script only then it is going to work because rest of your script is messing with the slideshow.

**Change the entire script from line 94 to line 125 in your HTML to this -**

```
<script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides(){
        var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides');
        for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
        slideIndex++;
        if(slideIndex > slides.length - 1){slideIndex = 0}
        loop();
    }
    function loop(){
        setTimeout(showSlides, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

If still you have a problem the please ask again.

Comment: so sorry for the late reply and it works amazingly thank you